# Error deploying to iPad Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous built version of your project

Tags: ipad, deployment

I'm running iOS 17.2 with Xcode 15.0.
My project deploys just fine to the simulator and to my iPhone 11 and my iPad Pro (3rd gen). However it refused to deploy to my iPad Air (4th gen).

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error MT1045: Failed to execute 'devicectl': 'devicectl -j /var/folders/b8/c1v8xb812734fnm5smgly07m0000gn/T/tmpVfI037.tmp device install app --device "Patrick MacDonald???s iPad (2)" /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/BigMath/5757214149f97f4d766edaa9479d80bfd87d8f175084625c705d9b45de84fbce/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/ipad13.1-17.2/BigMath.app' returned the exit code 1.          0

I've tried a number of things - clearing out the bin and obj folders and rebuilding. Cleaning the solution and rebuilding. In fact the project does not build when the object is my iPad Air. It builds just fine for the others